# Return to the last active context on an questionnaire Bot on Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I built a questionnaire bot on DialogFlow and I force a sequence using contexts. My output is the next intent and the input to set the current context.

The thing is that as it has several Yes and No questions I had to set lifespan as 1 to many of them. So the bot won't get confused. The side effect of this is when it goes to the fallback intent for any reason, no matter how many tries it gives, it won't understand what the user says as there is no active contexts anymore.

I'm already using fulfillment to set some conditional flows based in specific answers and to record and read data in Firebase.

Is there a way to retrieve the last active context so I can force the last context until having a valid input?

This bot will be running in Google Assistant interface.

tks!

Comment: Please add some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "last active context", since multiple Contexts may be active at once.

It sounds like, rather than having Contexts with a lifespan of 1, you want your Contexts to have a longer lifespan (in case they trigger an Intent that doesn't answer the question) so they can return to the path you want to ask them about.

To address the issue of multiple Intents that accept "yes" or "no", but are only valid in a particular Context, you can make a context inactive by setting its lifespan to 0 as part of an Outgoing Context or in the fulfillment for the Yes/No Intent that handles that Context.

Answer (score 0):

As Prisoner mentioned there is not "Last active context" feature within action on google, but if you work with 1 lifespan context there is a trick that you can use to see which contexts were from the previous intents.

If you work with context lifespans of 1, you can look into your context collection and look for any context which has a lifespan of undefined. These are output contexts set by your previous intent. In the below example I cycle through my contexts, take their name by looking for a common identiefier "_" and use the name to reset the expired context back to 1 using their previous parameters.

```
    const contextIdentifier = "_"
    const contextLifeSpan = 1;

    Object.values(conv.contexts.input).filter(c => !c.lifespan).forEach((context) => {
      const start = context.name.lastIndexOf(contextIdentifier);
      const end = context.name.length;
      const contextName = context.name.slice(start, end);

      conv.contexts.set(contextName, contextLifeSpan, context.parameters);
    });

    return conv;
```